# Positive variant of "taint"

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I want to use *taint* in a positive context, something along the lines of:

> I will have the opportunity to **taint** my life with the culture and experiences of others.

What would be a better word for this purpose?

Comment: You need to put more context to the question.  What do you want to taint your life with? For what purpose?

Comment: Taint always has a negative connotation.  It means pollute.  Depending on your response to @Rathony (which I encourage you to make), there might be a good choice, like *anoint*.

Comment: @Rathony Sorry for not including in the OP. The entire would be "I will have the opportunity to enhance my life with the culture and experiences of others."

Comment: @NajmSheikh Please try to include as much information as possible when posting a question. I would advise you to take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) to see how it works here.

Comment: Why didn't anyone say purify

Comment: @Neptunian: I think the normal usage of "purify" is to remove something bad (contaminates).  The OP wants to add good things.  For example, you wouldn't purify water by adding nutrients.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You might consider *enrich*. Like *enhance*, enrich means to increase the value of something.  [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/enrich) offers this definition:

> to make finer in quality, as by supplying desirable elements or ingredients

While *enhance* is positive and fits the context, I feel that *enrich* more aptly conveys the idea that not only are you steeping your life in positive things, but also that you personally value the opportunity to do so.

*Taint* doesn't imply that you want to besmirch your life or that you value doing so, but it does suggest a stain caused by deep soaking -- I feel *enrich* conveys the notion of "soaking yourself in something" better than *enhance* does.

Comment: Yep! That's the word I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 64):

I like *imbue*.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/imbue

> imbue
>
> verb (used with object), imbued, imbuing.
>
> 1. to impregnate or inspire, as with feelings, opinions, etc.:
>    The new political leader was imbued with the teachings of Mahatma Gandhi.
> 2. to saturate or impregnate with moisture, color, etc.
> 3. to imbrue.

Note the very close and etymologically related word "imbrue" as the third definition, which literally means "stain". As such, this suggestion might be closest to what you seek.

Comment: *Imbue* is a lovely word. This is a great suggestion.

Comment: *Imbue* wouldn't fit perfectly into the OP's sentence, IMO.  You would "imbue your life with [the something you gain from] the the culture and experience of others".  Without something in the brackets, I don't think "the culture and experience of others" is something you can directly imbue your life with.  *enrich* and *infuse* both work, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes I agree. The accepted answer is a better straight replacement for taint in that particular sentence. In any case, I prefer "by" to "with" when used with *taint* (and "with" is the only one that makes sense with *imbue*). I was offering another suggestion that would work with a different sentence structure.

Answer (score 31):

I think "[infuse](http://beta.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/infuse)" would work well.

> transitive verb: to cause to be permeated with something (as a principle or quality) that alters usually for the better

Answer (score 19):

Color?

As a verb,

> to give a special character or distinguishing quality to

and borrowing connotation from the noun form

> details in description, customs, speech, habits, etc., of a place or period

To me, `taint` brings to mind discoloring, perhaps from the similarity to `tint` and `paint`, although that might just be a personal bias.

Comment: I agree that *taint* has a sense of discoloring, like staining. I think *coloring* is a natural antonym for that sense.

Answer (score 8):

***suffuse***

> to gradually spread through or over

Usage is mostly past tense (***suffused***), and tends to refer to a soft introduction of light and colour.

Answer (score 7):

There is ['enhance'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/enhance?s=t)

> **Enhance** - verb (used with object), enhanced, enhancing.
>
> 1 - to raise to a higher degree; intensify; magnify: 
>   The candelight enhanced her beauty.
>
> 2 - to raise the value or price of: 
>   Rarity enhances the worth of old coins.
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

In your example 'I will have the opportunity to *enhance* my life with [this thing]...'

Answer (score 3):

My first thought was **augment**.

> make (something) greater by adding to it; increase

Answer (score 1):

*Contaminate* is generally negative but often used with an openly positive connotation, f.ex. to indicate the influence of a style on another. In my opinion it would fit nicely in your context.

ADDED: See f.ex. http://www.britannica.com/art/contamination .

Comment: I disagree - I've *never* heard it used with a positive connotation.

Comment: I've heard it used in a facetious sense. Maybe that's what you were thinking?

Comment: @shawnt00 et al. I mean f.ex. [_... you hear a reggae contaminated with other rhythms ..._](http://www.kalariseventi.com/urban-heiniken-festival-summer-2012-cabras-saturday-july-28/?lang=en), or [_... Tula Troubles – a contamination of ska and reggae that also combines ..._](http://www.radiominga.com/links/), or [_... a reggae/dancehall album contaminated both in the undertones ..._](http://reggae.today/index.php/component/tags/tag/509-newalbum), or just google it for any music genre or other forms of art. Whether it's Oxford - or even correct - English is surely debatable at will though.

Comment: I wasn't one of the three to vote up that comment just so you know. Are you sure that usage from your examples isn't kind of limited to the reggae scene?

Comment: @shawnt00 I know, I notified you just because you had asked a meaningful question about what I was referring to and I was just replying to that. If I could notify more than one user I would have notified FizzledOut too, and I think his/her comment makes a fair observation since he/she never heard the word in the sense I was talking about; that shows that its use is less common than I thought. I just wanted to point out that in my opinion it's definitely used in that sense too, and I still think it's a very good substitute for _taint_ in the sense the OP mentioned.

Comment: @shawnt00 Re _Are you sure that usage from your examples isn't kind of limited to the reggae scene?_ , yes, I'm sure.

Comment: I don't know the technical term but is it related to the way words like "bad", "wicked", "sick" are used to mean the opposite?

Comment: @shawnt00 Good point, probably yes. In the sense I always understood it it's related to one style influencing (i.e. contaminating in a positive, enriching way) another style. It applies to all forms of expression, not only music or other arts, but f.ex. fashion, cuisine etc.

Comment: I also tried Google but I couldn't find examples  Not sure how to narrow the search to that sense.

Comment: @shawnt00 Unfortunately I'm unable to allocate further time to this, so I will put [this Encyclopædia Britannica example](http://www.britannica.com/art/contamination) in my answer as it's not music-related. It is the first example that I found when googling for "style contamination", there are probably many more.

Answer (score 1):

I think `imbue` has the suggestion of changing the "color" of ones outward appearance. Another possibility with bread-baking analogy would be  `leaven` which would have the nice aspect of implying that other peoples experience was being used as "yeast".

Answer (score 1):

For a colorful variant, I like *[gild](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gild)*.

> to cover (something) with a thin layer of gold

Answer (score -1):

How about dope or doping?  Like in a transistor?

Comment: Doesn't doping usually have a negative connotation

Comment: "Dope your life, maaaaaaaaaaaan!"

Comment: I like it, but it's unlikely to be understood (worse, it's likely to be misunderstood) by non-technical folks. A small addition (the dopant) creates a large effect. Maybe *catalyze* would work.

Comment: Please fully explain your answer.